# English-speaking yeshivoth for beginners

Tags: product-recommendation, english, yeshiva-school

Can someone recommend a postsecondary yeshiva for English-speaking beginners in the US, Europe or Israel?

By "beginners" I mean people without good skills in gemara. For example, I studied Jewish law in an university in France but, in the religious world, my level would still be considered as low.

Comment: Obviously, a recommendation should be tailored to the individual student, so answers below will of [necessity](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/314) have to be general. That is, collected below should be a complete list of anglophone yeshivas for beginners, preferably with explanation (e.g. of how they differ from one another).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edit! I hope you get good answers. Please also consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: what age group?

Comment: @ray he said "postsecondary"

Answer (score 4):

[Shapell's](http://www.darchenoam.org/) is a very popular yeshiva in Israel for (not exclusively, but mostly) ba'alei teshuva with limited prior learning experience. Their focus is getting people up to speed quickly, and many people are able to go from basically no knowledge to being able to keep up with those who have been learning gemara for their whole lives within a couple of years. Pretty much any level of knowledge is welcome as their tiered system works for people who can barely read Hebrew all the way up to solid gemara learners. The yeshiva is for post-college-aged men.  There is also an affiliated seminary for women.

[Kollel Nefesh HaChaim](http://www.nefeshhachaim.org/) is an English-speaking Kollel in Jerusalem for young, married men who do not have extensive background knowledge in gemara.

Yeshivas [Ohr Someyach](http://ohr.edu/study_in_israel/) is another relatively popular Yeshiva located in the Maalot Dafna area of Jerusalem which has several 'tracks' and programs of study for students of varying levels of proficiency.  There is also an Ohr Someyach in Monsey, New York, which is also designed for beginners.  It is a much smaller institution than the Jerusalem Yeshiva.

[Aish Hatorah](http://www.aish.com/ai/ip/) has some popular programs though i cannot say based on personal experience.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I am not married.

Comment: Ohr Someyach is actually located in Arzei Habira, not the old city.

Answer (score 2):

The students of Rabbi Scheinberg Zatzal have opened Yeshiva Shaarei Chaim in Jerusalem and Yeshiva Derech Chaim in Brooklyn which caters to all learning levels.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Do you have more information about this yeshiva ? There is nothing online.

Comment: The number for Derech Chaim is 718-438-5476